# Resolving a promise in js using then method

Tags: javascript

If I'm having promise like this

```
 public async getCars(): Promise<Car[]> {
    if (!this.cars) {
      await this.fetchManufacturers();
    }
    return this.cars;
  }

public async fetchManufacturers(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      this.cars= await myService.getData.toPromise();
      this.cars$.next(this.cars);
    } catch (error) {
      this.cars$.error(error);
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to call getCars method

```
const carsPromise = this.dataService.getCars();
```

how can I resolve this promise?
// here I'm getting res as empty

I tried with

```
carsPromise.then((res) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      console.log(res[i].name);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: Did you check if `myService.getData.toPromise()` throws an error? The code as is should work. Here a [mcve in js](https://jsfiddle.net/m2y7csru/4/).

Comment: in this url you provide Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: res is not defined
    at carsPromise.then.cars

Comment: @user1765862 yes sorry, had `res`  instead of `cars`, I had corrected the link. it should be https://jsfiddle.net/m2y7csru/4/  and not the https://jsfiddle.net/m2y7csru/2/ version, so check that again.